# Can the Night King get past the wall without a dragon?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, game-of-thrones

I've always struggled with why everyone is afraid of the Night King in *Game of Thrones* and the army of the dead after it's revealed by Benjen that there's magic in the wall that prevent undead from passing through.

So, if Daenerys never flew Viserion North, who was then killed by the Night King...Does the Night King and the army of the dead have any way of breaking down / getting through the wall without Viserion or another dragon?

Note: I've read [these](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79170/why-worry-about-the-night-king-if-they-have-the-wall) answers, and none of them give a good enough explanation of how he would get past the wall without a dragon.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm not sure how this is a duplicate of that question...I specifically stated I've read that question in my question and the answers did not answer this question.

Comment: It is the same. Since we don't know and it's unlikely the show will ever explain what the NK intended to do I don't see the benefit of rehashing the same question again. Any **new** answers should be placed on the *original* question so they can all be found in one location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wall was not built to keep wildlings away as it has been a common fact in the world of Westeros before all of these NK related thing happened. So why was it built? NK seems powerful enough to gather an army of the dead and employ them to storm the giant gates and break open them to pass through it, he didn't need a Dragon to first tear down the Wall. However that did make it easy for his army to pass the wall.

But, there's a catch, Wall isn't (well, wasn't actually) just a physical barrier but also a magical spell was cast on the Wall to keep the Night King North of the Wall, the army of dead however were allowed through the wall but not the NK or his White Walker team. We know that because we have seen some Undead coming south of the wall, like in the first season when the magic spell was still active on the Wall.

Then, the cave in which three-eyed raven was also protected by not any physical barrier but only and only magic, so he was never able to go past it.

However, when NK left a mark on Bran the magic spell broke and he was able to go pass the boundaries of that Weirwood tree where three-eyed raven resided.

So coming back to your question, even if he had no dragons it would have been possible for him to pass through the wall given that Bran had his mark.

Comment: Ah okay. So assuming that the magic guarding the three-eyed raven is the same as the one guarding the wall, that magic is now broken due to the fact that the NK left his mark on Bran. I like this answer. Will give others a chance to answer as well before I accept it.